# Install Rserve return an error

Tags: macos, package-management, r

I am trying to install `Rserve` but it returns an error.

```
> install.packages('Rserve')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rserve_1.7-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 407390 bytes (397 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 397 KB

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
* installing *source* package 'Rserve' ...
** package 'Rserve' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking whether to compile the server... yes
checking whether to compile the client... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... 
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for memory.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/un.h usability... yes
checking sys/un.h presence... yes
checking for sys/un.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking netinet/tcp.h usability... yes
checking netinet/tcp.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/tcp.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking for memset... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for rmdir... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for srandomdev... yes
checking for library containing crypt... none required
checking crypt.h usability... no
checking crypt.h presence... no
checking for crypt.h... no
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking whether to enable IPv6... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking openssl/rsa.h usability... no
checking openssl/rsa.h presence... no
checking for openssl/rsa.h... no
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... no
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/client/cxx/Makefile
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RSserver.c -o RSserver.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c Rserv.c -o Rserv.o
Rserv.c:2976:16: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                                        if (fbufl < 0) fbufl = sfbufSize;
                                            ~~~~~ ^ ~
1 warning generated.
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c base64.c -o base64.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c http.c -o http.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c md5.c -o md5.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c oc.c -o oc.o
oc.c:72:11: warning: passing 'unsigned char [64]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        sha1hash(rbuf, sizeof(rbuf) - 1, hash);
                 ^~~~
./sha1.h:4:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'buf' here
void sha1hash(const char *buf, int len, unsigned char hash[20]);
                          ^
1 warning generated.
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c qap_decode.c -o qap_decode.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c qap_encode.c -o qap_encode.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c rsio.c -o rsio.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c session.c -o session.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c sha1.c -o sha1.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c standalone.c -o standalone.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c tls.c -o tls.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c websockets.c -o websockets.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c winembed.c -o winembed.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -o Rserve.so RSserver.o Rserv.o base64.o http.o md5.o oc.o qap_decode.o qap_encode.o rsio.o session.o sha1.o standalone.o tls.o websockets.o winembed.o -ldl -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
clang -DSTANDALONE_RSERVE -DDAEMON -I. -Iinclude -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -g -O2  -DRSERVE_PKG -I. -Iinclude    -o Rserve standalone.c md5.c session.c qap_decode.c qap_encode.c sha1.c base64.c websockets.c RSserver.c tls.c http.c oc.c rsio.c -ldl    -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation -ldl  
In file included from standalone.c:6:
./Rserv.c:2976:16: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                                        if (fbufl < 0) fbufl = sfbufSize;
                                            ~~~~~ ^ ~
1 warning generated.
oc.c:72:11: warning: passing 'unsigned char [64]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        sha1hash(rbuf, sizeof(rbuf) - 1, hash);
                 ^~~~
./sha1.h:4:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'buf' here
void sha1hash(const char *buf, int len, unsigned char hash[20]);
                          ^
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lintl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [server] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rserve'
* removing '/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.1_1/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rserve'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'Rserve' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/hh/dzflc4197x7bqqy1mfvsgmsr0000gn/T/Rtmp6t3hSs/downloaded_packages'
>
```

I can not understand where is the problem.

This is my R version :

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin14.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin14.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.1                         
year           2015                        
month          06                          
day            18                          
svn rev        68531                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
nickname       World-Famous Astronaut      
>
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Good start. I would ignore the warnings and focus on the error message: `ld: library not found for -lintl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` Did you install R from the pre-built packages or from `homebrew` perhaps? If you have brew, try installing [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) per this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370363/link-error-installing-rcpp-library-not-found-for-lintl and then modifying your ~/.R/Makevars configuration file to let the R compilation see the library that's "missing"

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, but I tried installing it using the [binary package for El Capitan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/index.html) and it installed fine.